# Is Allah part of Allah's 99 names?

Tags: allah, asma-ul-husna, names

Allah has 99 names but if you include Allah and Ahad that would make 100. So is Allah a part of the 99 names or not?

Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said:

'To God belongs 99 names, 100 minus 1, anyone who memorizes them will enter Paradise; He (God) is odd (odd number, he is the Only One), and He loves odd numbers (such as 99)'

Comment: [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_God_in_Islam); According to Qur'an and hadith, there are more than 99 names of Allah. 99 names are a special group of Allah's names, that are called asma-ul-husna. There are different opinion on which of Allah's names belong to asma-ul-husna.

Comment: Allah is proper noun used for Allah SWT while all the other names are adjectives or the names defining the property (Sifat)

Comment: Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said: 'To God belongs 99 names, 100 minus 1, anyone who memorizes them will enter Paradise; He (God) is odd (odd number, he is the Only One), and He loves odd numbers (such as 99)'

Comment: @Zohal this Hadith is gharib (ahad) and all the ahadith which quote a number of Allah's names have weaknesses here https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86%D9%89  you will find much more then 200 Names quoted by different scholars! Read also http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25621/tawheed-asma-was-siffat/25897#25897

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion there are two answers to your question. Firstly it is the combination of two Arabic words Al- and Ilah which is when joined, becomes Allah. Secondly it is specifically for the Lord of Heavens and it has not been derived from anything. However, this name is not included in 99 names.

Comment: "Al" in Allah isn't a word it's a part of it as i tried to explain in my Answer here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25621/tawheed-asma-was-siffat/25897#25897