# Tawheed asma was siffat

Tags: asma-ul-husna

My question is Allah name is ar rahman ar raheem al malik....but when we supplicate to Allah we say ya rahman ya malik without "Al" why? Please reply with evidences.

Comment: "Ya" is kinda like "O' God"; and  "Al" & "Ar" are kinda like "The God". One and the same, so when you're addressing God, you say, "O' God", not "The God"

Comment: Al in arabic means the and ya means oh. So we remove it when we are talking to God. It is like when an employee talk with his collegue about their boss he says "The boss did someThing" not "boss did something". When the employee speak to his boss he says "oh boss give me my salary" not "the boss give me my salary"

Comment: But its the perfect name of god how can we removenit...my name is ahmed if i remove ah from it my name med?

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with **Azam**'s answer who wrote answer in the comment.
The Arabic word 'Ya' means 'O'. This word is used to call a person.
For Example: "*Ya Hamza*" means "*O Hamza*".

Another word '*Al*', '*Ar*' and '*As*' etc means '*The*'. This word is used for a specific person.
For Example: ***The* teacher teaches a book**. In this example: ***The*** describes a **teacher** specific. Similarly 'Al', 'Ar' and 'As' is describes for a specific person or for a specific thing in Arabic grammar.

I hope you get an answer and totally agree with me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there's a little weakness in those Ahadith (hadits) which name a number of the names of Allah for example from those 99 Names (Imam at-Tirmidi -who was apparently the only one who narrated this "Hadith" who quotes the names - himself qualifies the Hadith as gharib!) many are neither quoted in the Qur'an nor (elsewhere) in the Sunna -explicitly-  as Names of Allah:

- الخافض - المعز المذل - العدل - الجليل - الباعث - المحصي - المبدىء - المعيد - المميت - الواجد - الماجد - الوالي - المقسط - المغني - المانع - الضار النافع - الباقي - الرشيد - الصبور

**Now to your question:** One important point is that except الله all the names are some kind of characterization which could also be applied on humans in some way. Therefore they are attributes in Arabic and to become a name they need the prefix al-, ar- etc. which is equal to "the" in English so ar-Rahman basically is "the" Rahman etc..

But the Name  [الله](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-ar/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87/) has even in Arabic some specification because it is pure oneness of God (tawhid) in a word itself! As it is significant to الإله = The (one and only) God but more expressive than it, as without the prefix  "ال" إلاه has a meaning (God)! And it includes already the article "al" but without it it wouldn't have any meaning! And as it is the name which describes or better summarizes all the characteristics of divinity it's forbidden to name anyone with this name (you can only name abd Allah but not Allah)

Therefor in Qur'an even Pharao who regarded himself as a God didn't use this name and said

> "And Pharaoh said, "O chiefs, I do not know of **any other god of yours
>   than myself**. Burn for me bricks of clay, O Haman, and build me a high
>   tower so that I may climb it to see the God of Moses for I consider
>   him to be an utter liar.""
>
> وَقَالَ فِرْعَوْنُ يَا أَيُّهَا الْمَلَأُ مَا عَلِمْتُ لَكُم مِّنْ
>   **إِلَهٍ** غَيْرِي فَأَوْقِدْ لِي يَا هَامَانُ عَلَى الطِّينِ فَاجْعَل
>   لِّي صَرْحًا لَّعَلِّي أَطَّلِعُ إِلَى إِلَهِ مُوسَى وَإِنِّي
>   لَأَظُنُّهُ مِنَ الْكَاذِبِينَ
>   [Al-Qasas [28:38]](http://legacy.quran.com/28/38)
>
> "I am your Lord, the highest."
>
> فَقَالَ أَنَا رَبُّكُمُ الأَعْلَى
>   [Surat an-Naazi'at [79:24]](http://legacy.quran.com/79/24)

So when you call Allah in dua' by his name الله you say Ya Allah (O Allah) but when you call him by some characteristic name these names including their articles "al","ar"... obey to grammatical rules and disappear!

By the way if we count all the -different- names the scholars have quoted we find some [276 names](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86%D9%89)

And Allah knows best!

Comment: I'm afraid, to me, it looks like totally the opposite way around, bro. Allah can have nameless millions of revelations and manifestations to the eyes of a true Salik (سالک), hence can have nameless number of names. Those names that have been narrated and have become commonplace among ordinary people are those with the easiest acceptance.

Comment: Apologies if I was off the point; I concluded from the first paragraph in your answer (and apparently missed the last!) that since some of the names are not mentioned in Quran they are not valid names. all my fault...