# If it really is makruh to name a child after an angel, then why do so many Muslims have the names Maalik and Raqib?

Tags: naming, malaikah, makruh

Some scholars regard using the names of angels (peace be upon them) as makrooh. (Source: https://islamqa.info/en/1692)

Is there any hadith or verse of Quran that supports this? I don't want to jump into conclusions but I think this might be from a weak hadith. Because if it was really makruh to name someone after an angel, then why do so many Muslims have the name Maalik and Raqib? In case you don't know, these are also names of angels in Islam (Source: http://www.rahmahmuslimhomeschool.co.uk/index/al-malaikah-the-angels-the-names-and-the-responsibilities/).

I'm sure you know Al-Maalik and Ar-Raqib are also names of Allah and we are allowed to name children after names of Allah as long as we omit the "Al-". Would that mean we can name a child after any of the names of Allah except for Maalik and Raqib?

Comment: I think that al-Malik الملك , al-Maleek المَلِيك and Maalik-u-l-Mulk مالِكُ المُلْك are names of Allah not Maalik  المالك http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25621/tawheed-asma-was-siffat/25897#25897. And I suppose that this applies to the non-Arabic names in first place. As مالك is a common and wide spread Arabic name. And whether Raqeeb is indeed a name of an angel is a discussed matter!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05Y2V7U26Fc  as it is declared in this video , scholars have differed on this question ( some said it is `makrouh` , and some said it is `allowed` because the hadeeth is weak , and some was in between , said `only if the name was at the time of the prophet` , like malik like in "anas ibn malik" and the prophet didn't reject the name , it is ok.

Comment: @anaccountant and you should put an answer explaining all this.

Answer (score 1):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

I specially called on my shiekh and we had discussion about your this specific question.

Now, firstly,

Al-Maalik is name of allah, as allah says in quran:

> **مَالِكِ يَوْمِ الدِّينِ**

and many other places, he has used name maalik for himself, so there is no issue in this name.

Also name Raqib

> لَّا يَحِلُّ لَكَ النِّسَاءُ مِن بَعْدُ وَلَا أَن تَبَدَّلَ بِهِنَّ
>   مِنْ أَزْوَاجٍ وَلَوْ أَعْجَبَكَ حُسْنُهُنَّ إِلَّا مَا مَلَكَتْ
>   يَمِينُكَ ۗ **وَكَانَ اللَّهُ عَلَىٰ كُلِّ شَيْءٍ رَّقِيبًا**
>
> and
>
> لَّا يَحِلُّ لَكَ النِّسَاءُ مِن بَعْدُ وَلَا أَن تَبَدَّلَ بِهِنَّ
>   مِنْ أَزْوَاجٍ وَلَوْ أَعْجَبَكَ حُسْنُهُنَّ إِلَّا مَا مَلَكَتْ
>   يَمِينُكَ ۗ **وَكَانَ اللَّهُ عَلَىٰ كُلِّ شَيْءٍ رَّقِيبًا**

So, **there is no issue in having names like abdul-maalik, and abdul-raqeeb etc because when we are saying abdul-maalik, everyone know that we are referring to the Allah not the angels** so there is no issue.

And also naming after names of malaaika is not bad, until or unless these are under the instructions on naming in islam. i.e there meaning is suitable for naming human beings.

For example, when i google the meaning of izrael, i found:

***The name Azrael is a Hebrew baby name. In Hebrew the meaning of the name Azrael is: God's help.***

So, naming this is nothing prohibited, same goes for jibrael. Now, **one thing is clear we can have angels names for us, though some scholars have disliked it. But there is no strong base for this**.

A **more reasonable view of some scholars is on naming girls on names of angels**, they say its makrooh **because mushrikeen used to say the angels are daughters of Allah**. So we should not name girls on names of angels to avoid any mis-understanding. But this is also not a strong point, **no one think we have such belief, so there is no confusion, hence no issue in this too**.

Prophet ﷺ said:

> "**Leave that which makes you doubt for that which does not make you
>   doubt.**" (Narrated by Termithi and Nasaee, and Tirmithi said it is true
>   and fine hadith.)

**Lastly:** Now the last thing about **using Allah's names removing Al- from it**.

Let me quote:

*The **names of Allaah**, insofar as they are applied only to Him – fall into **two categories**: 


1.

**Names that only belong to Him**, may He be glorified and exalted, and cannot be given to anyone but Him, such as the names Allaah, al-Rabb (the Lord or Cherisher), al-Rahmaan (the Most Gracious), al-Ahad (the Unique), al-Samad (the Self-Sufficient Master, Whom all creatures need, He neither eats nor drinks), al-Mutakabbir (the Majestic), and so on. **It is not permissible to call any human being by these names, according to scholarly consensus**. 

2.

**Names which do not apply only to Him, and which may be applied to human beings**, so **it is permissible to call people by them**, such as Samee’ (hearing), Baseer (seeing), ‘Aliy (high, exalted), Hakeem (wise), Rasheed (wise). Some of the most well known Sahaabah were called by these names, such as ‘Ali ibn Abi Taalib and Hakeem ibn Hizaam (may Allaah be pleased with them). 


**What is forbidden is only the names which apply only to the Lord, such as Allaah and al-Rahmaan.***

From: [Is calling people by the names of Allaah regarded as shirk?](https://islamqa.info/en/114309)(have a look on this for details)

I hope this answers the question.

Jazakallah.

### Allah knows best